# Frame from iOs 9 constraints

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I am having trouble with getting the actual width out of my view. I have added my UIView() as "progressBar" to the controller's view but I need to get the width in order to execute some other code.

Is there any possible way I can get the object's width out of those constraints?

Thank you for helping! Appreciate it.

```
progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(progressBar)

    progressBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    progressBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -430).isActive = true
    progressBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    progressBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4).isActive = true
```

Comment: What about `progressBar.frame.size.width`?

Comment: Two choices - with *only* those constraints, you can get the width in *viewWillLoadSubviews()* or *viewDidLoadSubviews()*. But **not** in *viewDidLoad()*. The other alternative is to change the *widthAnchor* constraint to be a constant.

Comment: The bar's frame is a CGRect.zero. What if I need the width inside a custom Class, subclassed of a UIControl?